# NestJS PermissionsGuard, user permissions is always undefined using Auth0 valid token

Tags: jwt, nestjs, token, auth0, auth-guard

I know my token is valid and contains the permissions alongside the email and role, since when I use jwt.io on what is received in the back I get something like this:

```
{
  "https://xxx/roles": ["admin"],
  "https://xxx/email": "test.test@gmail.com",
  "iss": "https://yyy/",
  "sub": "auth0|62fe8aa3e6af28270479a495",
  "aud": [
    "https://xxx",
    "https://yyy"
  ],
  "iat": 1692728774,
  "exp": 1692815174,
  "azp": "EOHLdEZS8KaK5CfpscR9ebZzd9ibyy4C",
  "scope": "openid read:current_user update:current_user_metadata",
  "permissions": [
    "create:ingredients",
    (...)
    "update:users"
  ]
}
```

I can't find a single way to get my user email or permission (in token['https://xxx/email']) or simply the permissions in the guard and/or controller.
I know they are supposed to be in "context.getArgs()[0].user.permissions" & "context.getArgs()[0].user['https://xxx/email']" but it's always undefined

I created the following decorators:

```
export const Permissions = (...permissions: string[]) => {
  //setting permissions
  return SetMetadata('permissions', permissions);
};
```

```
export const AuthUser = createParamDecorator(
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  (data: unknown, ctx: any): IUserToken => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  }
);
```

And the following guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class PermissionsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const routePermissions = this.reflector.get<string[]>(
      'permissions',
      context.getHandler()
    );

    if (!routePermissions) {
      return true;
    }

    const userPermissions = context.getArgs()[0].user.permissions;
    console.log(userPermissions); // Always undefined

    const hasPermission = () => {
      return routePermissions.every((routePermission) =>
        userPermissions.includes(routePermission)
      );
    };

    return hasPermission();
  }
}
```

I then added the decorators to my endpoint:

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), PermissionsGuard)
  @Get()
  @Permissions('read:users')
  async find(
    @AuthUser() user: IUserToken,
    @Res() response: Response
  ): Promise<Response> {
    console.log(user); // Always undefined
```

Comment: What exactly is `request.user`? Can you share a CURL/postman request on how your api call looks like?